# Count aggregation not working in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to apache pig and I'm facing a problem in pig programming. I want to count the number of employees reporting under every manager. But I don't think I am getting the right output from this code. Need your help.

here's the source data file:

```
7369,SMITH,CLERK,7902,1980-12-17,800.00,NULL,20
7499,ALLEN,SALESMAN,7698,1981-02-20,1600.00,300.00,30
7521,WARD,SALESMAN,7698,1981-02-22,1250.00,500.00,30
7566,JONES,MANAGER,7839,1981-04-02,2975.00,NULL,20
7654,MARTIN,SALESMAN,7698,1981-09-28,1250.00,1400.00,30
7698,BLAKE,MANAGER,7839,1981-05-01,2850.00,NULL,30
7782,CLARK,MANAGER,7839,1981-06-09,2450.00,NULL,10
7788,SCOTT,ANALYST,7566,1982-12-09,3000.00,NULL,20
7839,KING,PRESIDENT,NULL,1981-11-17,5000.00,NULL,10
7844,TURNER,SALESMAN,7698,1981-09-08,1500.00,0.00,30
7876,ADAMS,CLERK,7788,1983-01-12,1100.00,NULL,20
7900,JAMES,CLERK,7698,1981-12-03,950.00,NULL,30
7902,FORD,ANALYST,7566,1981-12-03,3000.00,NULL,20
7934,MILLER,CLERK,7782,1982-01-23,1300.00,NULL,10
```

here's the code:

```
data_mgr = load '/users/Desktop/Employees.rtf' using 
PigStorage(',') as (empno:int, empname:chararray, job:chararray, 
mgr:int, hiredate:chararray, sal:float, comm:float, dept:int);

data_emp = load '/users/Desktop/Employees.rtf' using 
PigStorage(',') as
(empno:int, empname:chararray, job:chararray, mgr:int, 
hiredate:chararray, sal:float, comm:float, dept:int);

joined = join data_mgr by mgr, data_emp by empno;

select1 = foreach joined generate data_mgr::empno as mgrid, 
data_mgr::empname as mgrname, data_emp::empno as empno;

grouped = group select1 by ($0, $1);

select2 = foreach grouped generate group, COUNT(select1) as 
no_of_reportees;

ordered = order select2 by no_of_reportees desc;

dump ordered;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 emp_data = LOAD '/users/Desktop/Employees.rtf' USING PigStorage(',') AS (empno:int, empname:chararray, job:chararray, mgrid:int, hiredate:chararray, sal:float, comm:float, dept:int);
 mgr_group = GROUP  emp_data BY mgrid;
 emo_count = FOREACH mgr_grp GENERATE group AS mgr_id, COUNT(emp_data) AS Count;
 emp_count_ordered = ORDER emp_count BY Count DESC;
 DUMP emp_count_ordered;
```

Note : You can further use JOIN operation with initial dataset to fetch mgr name.

Do you mean something like this ? (though I have not tested)

```
data_emp = load '/users/Desktop/Employees.rtf' using PigStorage(',') as (empno:int, empname:chararray, job:chararray, mgrid:int, hiredate:chararray, sal:float, comm:float, dept:int);

data_mgr = load '/users/Desktop/Employees.rtf' using PigStorage(',') as (empno:int, empname:chararray, job:chararray, mgrid:int, hiredate:chararray, sal:float, comm:float, dept:int);

emp_mgr_join = join data_emp by empno, data_mgr by mgrid;

emp_mgr_join_sub = foreach emp_mgr_join generate data_mgr::mgrid as mgrid, data_mgr::empname as mgrname, data_emp::empno as empno;

emp_mgr_grouped = group emp_mgr_join_sub by mgrid;

emp_mgr_count = foreach emp_mgr_grouped generate group AS mgr_id, emp_mgr_join_sub.mgrname as mgr_name, COUNT(emp_mgr_join_sub) as no_of_reportees;

ordered = order emp_mgr_count by no_of_reportees desc;

dump ordered;
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want to implement this using a self-join. I am a beginner to Pig and I would like to understand the usage of self-joins. Could you please tell me how this can be done using self-join?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with my code. If anybody could point out where the problem is, that would be really helpful.

Comment: @PradeepRajagopalan , I have updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Thank you. But I am not getting right output. Please see the output I am getting:

(7499,{(ALLEN)},1)
(7934,{(MILLER)},1)
(7902,{(FORD)},1)
(7900,{(JAMES)},1)
(7876,{(ADAMS)},1)
(7844,{(TURNER)},1)
(7788,{(SCOTT)},1)
(7782,{(CLARK)},1)
(7698,{(BLAKE)},1)
(7654,{(MARTIN)},1)
(7566,{(JONES)},1)
(7521,{(WARD)},1)
(,{(SMITH)},0)

Comment: Although I am selecting only mgr ID's, I am getting all emp ID's and a count of 1 for every employee. Tried left outer join as well. But it doesn't work too